# Changing data type of a model property without affecting data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are using Code First approach in one of our ASP.NET MVC Core app. We have a table with lots of data in it and we want to change the data type of one of its column from `string` to `int`.

The column is storing only two integers, being "1" and "2". How will we do it using Package Manager console command (or something like that) without affecting the data.

So, in the following model we need to change `OrderType` from `string` to `int` without affecting existing data in the SQL Server database:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { set; get; }
    public string OrderType { set; get; }
    public int OrderYear { set; get; }
    public string OrderLoc { set; get; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

We're using VS2015 with latest updates. Following may be a better explanation of our question:

In ASP.NET Core - Code First model sometimes you can make certain changes to a model and run a migration command to keep the changes in sync with the database that was originally created using Code First approach. I'm looking for such a migration command so if data type of a model property is changed to a compatible type the existing data in the corresponding column in the database table remains intact. Please note that in our case since column `OrdererType` is holding values 1 and 2 as string the existing data type `string` is compatible to data type `int`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not affecting existing data"? You can't change a database column's type and leave the values for that column in existing rows alone.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added a new UPDATE section that may answer your question. I also noticed that your edit to my question may have polished my question a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue as follows. Following are **my observations**:

It turned out that after making any changes to model - such as adding/deleting a property, changing a data type of a property or even deleting an existing entire model or adding a new model - if you run the following command in the `Package Manager` console of Visual Studio, a new migration file will be created - under Migrations folder in Visual Studio - reflecting those changes. And then when you run the second command shown below all your new changes will be reflected in the existing database (that was originally created using `Code First` approach). That's the changed data types in model will be changed accordingly in the corresponding SQL Db, deleted/added properties in the model will cause corresponding columns in the corresponding table in the corresponding SQL Db to be added/deleted accordingly, etc. etc. During all this process all your existing data will be intact if the corresponding new data types are compatible with the old data in the old data type etc.

**How does it all happen**: Whenever we run `add-migration` command Visual Studio creates a table called `__EFMigrationsHistory` in the database that keeps track of the changes created in the migration file.

**Package Manage Console Commands**:

1. First command:

   PM> add-migration myNewMigration -context myWebProjContext

Note: When you run the above command, following message would warn you to review your changes in the newly created migration before you run the next command that would update the database reflecting all your changes:

```
An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
```

1. Second command:

   PM> update-database -context myWebProjContext

**For example**

After I made the following changes to the following model and ran the above commands, the Orders table in SQL Db had data type of `OrderType` as tinyint, and the columns OrderName and OrderDesc were dropped from the SQL db:

**Old Model**

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { set; get; }
    public string OrderType { set; get; }
    public int OrderYear { set; get; }
    public string OrderLoc { set; get; }
    public string OrderName { set; get; }
    public string OrderDesc { set; get; }
}
```

**Modification to the above Model**: Here I changed the data type of `OrderType` from string to byte. And deleted the last two properties `OrderName` and `OrderDesc`

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { set; get; }
    public byte OrderType { set; get; }
    public int OrderYear { set; get; }
    public string OrderLoc { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you have to do is:

`PM: Add-Migration SomeNewName`

(if 'SomeNewName' is already in your migration folder, delete it or give a new name.)

```
PM: Update-Database
```